# How to eliminate API level factor while supporting different screen sizes in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making an Android Application. Basicly everything done to support different screen sizes. To support different screen sizes I used a theme and I am getting WindowWidthSizeClass and assigning the devices dimensions like if it is Compact Small I have created proper values for it..

Theme code snippet is below :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    activity: Activity = LocalContext.current as MainActivity,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    val window = calculateWindowSizeClass(activity = activity)
    val config = LocalConfiguration.current

    var typography = CompactTypography
    var appDimens = CompactDimens

    when(window.widthSizeClass) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> {
            if (config.screenWidthDp <= 360) {
                appDimens = CompactSmallDimens
                typography = CompactSmallTypography
            } else if (config.screenWidthDp < 400) {
                appDimens = CompactMediumDimens
                typography = CompactMediumTypography
            } else {
                appDimens = CompactDimens
                typography = CompactTypography
            }
        }

        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> {
            if (config.screenWidthDp <= 750) {
                appDimens = MediumDimens
                typography = MediumTypography
            } else {
                appDimens = MediumDimensExtra
                typography = MediumExtraTypography
            }

        } else -> {
        appDimens = ExpandedDimens
        typography = ExpandedTypography
        }
    }

    AppUtils(appDimens = appDimens) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colorScheme = colorScheme,
            typography = typography,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

It is working correct for everything now but one thing except. I have a FloatingActionButton when I click on it it expands and two icons appearing. These icons sizes differing depending on API level... For example if I use Pixel 3 with API 24 the size is working correct but when I use Pixel 3 with API 29 or 30 its size is reducing. I have added the images of Pixel 3 API 30 and Pixel 3 API 24. As you can see below both of the devices are same but Icons' sizes are different.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on Canvas. I think Canvas is differing between API level. When I remove Canvas and used something instead of it my problem resolved.

Comment: It doesn't differ between apis because canvas is Spacer with Modifier.drawBehind modifier, nothing special. But depending on how you draw, using pixels instead of dp, you might get different result depending on density of device

Comment: I was only using Dp values but I was also using Scale maybe it may cause an error.